# XSLT 1.0 Share Curent value to other template

Tags: xslt

in the following code I display a first page representing different operations carried out in different premises, when you select a link a new page opens with the associated image and the different information associated with the image but I would like to be able to reduce the number of informations associate according to the local link to the links.
thanks to XSLT/Muenchian grouping :
<xsl:key name="distinct-inspection-types"
match="EntityRef/Attribute[@name='JV_Inspection_Type']/Value" use="." />
I can sort my distinct values ​​and divide my operations with these same values and display them thanks to
<xsl:value-of select="." />

My problem is that I want to retrieve the value of <xsl:value-of select="." /> and use it on the page accessed through the links in order to sort the information on it.

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  
   <xsl:param name="P_DataXMLRoot"
      select="document(/WKIXMLViewRoot/WKIXMLDataFile/@name)/WKIXMLDataRoot" />
   <xsl:param name="P_ContextID" select="/WKIXMLViewRoot/WKIXMLContextEntity/@ref_id" />
   <xsl:template match="/WKIXMLViewRoot">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./WKIXMLContextEntity" />
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_ContextEntity" match="/WKIXMLViewRoot/WKIXMLContextEntity">
      
      <xsl:if test="string(@has_views)='true'">
        
         <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_UnAssignedSlides" />
         <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_Requirements">
      
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./WKIXMLContextChildren/WKIXMLContextChild">
         <xsl:sort select="@index" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      
   </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:key name="distinct-inspection-types"
      match="EntityRef/Attribute[@name='JV_Inspection_Type']/Value" use="." />
   
   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_ContextChild"
      match="/WKIXMLViewRoot/WKIXMLContextEntity/WKIXMLContextChildren/WKIXMLContextChild">
      <xsl:variable name="_RefID" select="@ref_id" />
      <xsl:variable name="_InsID" select="@ins_id" />
      <xsl:variable name="_URL" select="@url" />
      <xsl:variable name="_Icon" select="@icon" />
      <xsl:variable name="_RefNode" select="$P_DataXMLRoot/ProductionSystemStructure/*[@id=$_RefID]" />
      <xsl:variable name="_InsNode" select="$P_DataXMLRoot/ProductionSystemStructure/*[@id=$_InsID]" />
      <xsl:variable name="_RefName" select="$_RefNode/Name" />
      <xsl:variable name="_InsName" select="$_InsNode/Name" />
               <xsl:variable name="_RefNodeName" select="local-name($_RefNode)" />
      <!-- <xsl:value-of select="text($_URL)" /> -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$_RefName">
         <xsl:for-each
            select="//EntityRef/Attribute[@name='JV_Inspection_Type']/Value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('distinct-inspection-types', .)[1])]">
            <table >
               <tr>
                  <td >
                     <b>
                        <a href="{$_URL}">
                           <xsl:value-of select="$RefName" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                        </a>
                     </b>
                  </td>
                  <td >
                     <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <br />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_OperationInstance_Any"
      match="/WKIXMLDataRoot/ProductionSystemStructure/ProductionOperationInst">
      <xsl:variable name="_OperationInsID" select="@id" />

      <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_ContextEntity" />
     
      
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_Requirements">
      <xsl:variable name="_RequirementsNodeSet"
         select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKIRequirementsRoot/Requirement[ImplementingEntityRef/@Ref_ID=$P_ContextID]" />
      <xsl:variable name="_SpecifiedAttributes"
         select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot/EntityRef" />
      <h1 >Métro</h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="$_SpecifiedAttributes">
         <xsl:if
            test="Attribute[@name = 'Title']/Value != ''">
            <xsl:if
               test="Attribute[@name = 'JV_Inspection_Type']/Value = 'métro'">
               <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_Table_Requierements" />
               <br></br>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      
      <h1>Bdl</h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="$_SpecifiedAttributes">
         <xsl:if
            test="Attribute[@name = 'Title']/Value != ''">
            <xsl:if
               test="Attribute[@name = 'JV_Inspection_Type']/Value = 'Bdl'">
               <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_Table_Requierements" />
               <br></br>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      
      <h1>Rugosité</h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="$_SpecifiedAttributes">
         <xsl:if
            test="Attribute[@name = 'Title']/Value != ''">
            <xsl:if
               test="Attribute[@name = 'JV_Inspection_Type']/Value = 'Rugosité'">
               <xsl:call-template name="WKITemplate_Table_Requierements" />
               <br></br>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_Table_Requierements">
      <table border="1">
         
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  <xsl:call-template name="replace-br-tags-with-semicolon">
                     <xsl:with-param name="input" select="Attribute[@name = 'Title']/Value" />
                  </xsl:call-template>
                  
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  N° CTF Client
               </td>
               <td class="column_right">
                  <xsl:call-template name="replace-br-tags-with-semicolon">
                     <xsl:with-param name="input"
                        select="Attribute[@name = 'JV_CTF_Customer_Identification']/Value" />
                  </xsl:call-template>
                  
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  N° CTF Interne
               </td>
               <td class="column_right">
                  <xsl:call-template name="replace-br-tags-with-semicolon">
                     <xsl:with-param name="input"
                        select="Attribute[@name = 'JV_CTF_Internal_Identification']/Value" />
                  </xsl:call-template>
                  
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template name="replace-br-tags-with-semicolon">
      <xsl:param name="input" />
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($input, '&lt;br/&gt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, '&lt;br/&gt;')" />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-br-tags-with-semicolon">
               <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, '&lt;br/&gt;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($input)" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template name="WKITemplate_UnAssignedSlides">
      <xsl:variable name="_3DAssociatedSlideSet"
         select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionsRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation[@WKIOperationRef_ID = $P_ContextID]/WKIInstructionAssociationRoot/WKIInstructionToViewAssociationList/WKIInstructionToViewAssociation" />
      <xsl:variable name="_3DSlideSet"
         select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionsRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation[@WKIOperationRef_ID = $P_ContextID]/WKISlide[@is_image='Yes']" />
      <xsl:variable name="_3DSlideSetCount" select="count($_3DSlideSet)" />
      <xsl:variable name="_3DSlideOVSet"
         select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionsRoot/WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation[@WKIOperationRef_ID = $P_ContextID]/WKISlide[@is_image='Yes']/OrientationView" />
      <xsl:variable name="_3DSlideOVSetCount" select="count($_3DSlideOVSet)" />
      <xsl:variable name="_Separator">
         <xsl:if test="count($_3DAssociatedSlideSet) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:variable>
      
      <xsl:variable name="_3DAssociatedSlideIndexes">
         <xsl:for-each select="$_3DAssociatedSlideSet">
            <xsl:value-of select="$_Separator" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@ViewIndex" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$_Separator" />
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="$_3DSlideSetCount">         
         <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">      
            <tr>
               <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"
                   >
                  <b>Views</b>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$_3DSlideSet">
               <xsl:variable name="_3DSlideIndex" select="@index" />
               <tr >                  
                  <td>
                     <img alt="{ ./File/FileName/text() }"
                          src="{ ./File/FileLocation/text() }"
                           />
                 
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>    
         </table>   
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Value">
      <p>
         <xsl:call-template name="normalize-text">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template name="normalize-text">
      <xsl:param name="text" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
`<?xml version='1.0'?>
<WKIXMLDataRoot xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
   
    <WKIPreviewDataRoot>
        <WKI3DWorkInstructionsRoot>
            <WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation WKIOperationRef_ID="ID_2">
                <WKISlide index="1" is_image="Yes">
                    <Name>Vue.1</Name>
                    <File>
                        <FileName>gop-00005342.A.View.1.f375ca97_5c04_65167171_5b7fd.png</FileName>
                        <FileLocation>.\gop-00005342.A.View.1.f375ca97_5c04_65167171_5b7fd.png</FileLocation>
                    </File>
                </WKISlide>
            </WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation>
            <WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation WKIOperationRef_ID="ID_4">
                <WKISlide index="1" is_image="Yes">
                    <Name>View.1</Name>
                    <File>
                        <FileName>gop-00005343.A.View.1.e0d3aeb6_7b80_650410bc_6c4cd.png</FileName>
                        <FileLocation>.\gop-00005343.A.View.1.e0d3aeb6_7b80_650410bc_6c4cd.png</FileLocation>
                    </File>
                </WKISlide>
            </WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation>
            <WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation WKIOperationRef_ID="ID_5">
                <WKISlide index="1" is_image="Yes">
                    <Name>Vue.1</Name>
                    <File>
                        <FileName>gop-00005344.A.View.1.f375ca97_5c04_65167174_5ba67.png</FileName>
                        <FileLocation>.\gop-00005344.A.View.1.f375ca97_5c04_65167174_5ba67.png</FileLocation>
                    </File>
                </WKISlide>
            </WKI3DWorkInstructionForOperation>
           
        </WKI3DWorkInstructionsRoot>
        <WKIAttachedDocumentsRoot />
        <WKIUserSpecifiedUnitsRoot />
        <WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot>
            <EntityRef Ref_ID="ID_39">
                </Attribute>
               
                <Attribute name="JV_Inspection_Type" display_name="" native="true">
                    <Value>Bdl</Value>
                </Attribute>
              
            </EntityRef>
<EntityRef Ref_ID="ID_12">
               
                <Attribute name="JV_Inspection_Type" display_name="" native="true">
                    <Value>Bdl</Value>
                </Attribute>
               
            </EntityRef>
  </WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot>
    </WKIPreviewDataRoot>
</WKIXMLDataRoot>`
```

[Example result first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpWTp.png)

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem (see: [mcve]) and add the expected result (as code within your question, not image in external link).

Comment: I try to reduce more without broke the reproductibility of my probleme please let me know for anything else. thank you